# Texas Land System Grid data

Tags: data-request, geospatial, government

I am working on R&D for Texas Grid data.Currently, I download https://tnris.org/data-catalog/entry/usgs-quad-grid/ data.But I don't know which is the actual Grid data for Texas.For example, Alberta provenance using DLS system Grid data.

So which is the Land system follow Texas and where I can get data?

Please, Any help to get a downloadable file or reference link to get Grid data for Texas Land system.

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the Texas National Resources Information System directly. https://tnris.org/contact/ Phone: 512-463-8337. Mailing address: 1700 N. Congress, Room B-40, Austin, Texas, 78701.

Comment: Okay, thanks for reply @csk.i will see reference link.